# Looking for a rare or reserved UTF-8 code, for no-colision with text content

Tags: algorithm, utf-8

I have algoritm that process a "generic UTF-8 multilingual big text", and it need to use a "neutral symbol" that never used in the text. I first elected an aleatory big four-byte UTF8 that have visual representation on my text editor, as 171581 ( = F0 A9 B8 BD), but it is not the "perfect choice" because create a restriction on the text (japanese) language...

**There are a reserved UTF-8 char that never will be a content and is not a control?**

PS: I am using now a "safe" EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH A044 (), seems good choice, but I can't see on my editor.

Comment: Must it be valid Unicode, or is just being convertibel to UCS-4 and not needing more than 4 bytes enough?

Comment: Any valid UTF-8 char that is recognized by a PCRE (`/u`) regular expression.

Comment: So, it must be Perl-accepted? No idea whether the APIs you want to use validate the input-sequence.

Comment: What about arbitrarily selecting from the PUA?

Comment: (ops sorry correcting english) Well, [it is "full UTF-8 compatible"](http://www.pcre.org/) and used in so many places that are not Perl (Java, PHP, Python, etc.)... It is UTF-8, and any clue are welcome! PS: what is the PUA? hum.. [Private Use Areas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).. yes... I will test (but imagine that will not see chars at editor)

Comment: [PUA is private-use-area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). And "It's full UTF-8 compatible" does not help that much, as I asked what your API does on non-unicode. Explode? Ignore?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, use char of the PUA, like "" that google not see content!

Comment: About "what your API does on non-unicode": impossible (or not understand), the input (and all framework) is UTF-8.

Comment: You know why UTF-8 is restricted to 0x10ffff as the highest codepoint it may code? Why not 0x1fffff, that's easily in reach for 4 bytes, or even 0x7fffffff with 6? Because of UTF-16. So, if your APIs are transparent to not-quite-unicode-codepoint-anymore-things (quite reasonable), they are the obvious and best choice.

Comment: Unicode defines certain code points such as U+FFFE and U+FFFF as non-characters. They have a valid encoding as UTF-8 but no character properties, and should not be used in Unicode text.

Comment: why can't you use `'\0'` (NUL, U+0000)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, as Deduplicator and Joni shows, PUA characteres are valid UTF8 (for use as logical separator, valid regex, etc.) and never will apear in a text of any language. NUL can be used in a convention of [Null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), so, is not a good choice.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: 1. forget the word UTF8, use the word Unicode (utf-8 is a character encoding that you can use to convert Unicode text into bytes and back, [here's picture](http://taniquetil.com.ar/unicode.png)). utf-8 is not the only encoding e.g., utf-16 is also common (it is not the recommendation to use it). 2. The conflict is inherited in PUA (different entities interpret the same PUA codepoints differently) i.e., a text may contain PUA characters. 3. Are you working in C? Normally, you shouldn't see U+0000 in a text (string object has the explicit length). Like with PUA, conflict is possibl

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, fast answer: please check [below my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25828874/287948), it is a Wiki, you can edit... About 1. Yes good picture. About 2. I need only a text separator that is not content, and use later in a split or regex operarations... so it is an internal representation on my control.  About 3. no but the question is generic.. no conflict if the problem is about "content" concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(to not delete the question here my extension of the @Deduplicator commented answer)

Perhaps, even all content of the Wikipedia and [PubMed Central](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/) (PMC) articles together  have no line with this "" Egyptian hierogliph character... But when I use it in a Google search, it returns a lot of content (~1830 results). The same occur for any other character of any other language, like "" or "ٲ"... "Rare use" character is not warranty of "never used", "no content with it".

By other hand, if we search with Wikipedia, Google, PMC, or any another "search in the UTF-8 content" engine, no one returns a result from **""** (F002) or **""** (F003) because they are not "content characters", neither some kind of control (ex. [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)) that can corrupt a string. "" and ""  are **examples of  [PUA (Private Use Area) characteres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)**.

As demonstred above, the "no-colision" here (in this kind of problem) depends on the concept of "content". If you suppose that your string is a "UTF-8 content", any PUA character is will be the best choice.